# JSONP Ajax Syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to alert the visitor of my webpage with a country code provided by a JSONP endpoint. However, I cannot seem to get this working! And all the answers on the web seem confusing!

**The following is returned from the endpoint:**

```
{
    "pcCartCt": 0,
    "pcCountryCode": "au",
    "pcCountrySite": "WWW",
    "pcExpDomCt": 0,
    "pcFirstName": "",
    "pcIsCdc": false,
    "pcIsDiscount": false,
    "pcIsGdEmployee": false,
    "pcIsTrusted": false,
    "pcLanguageCookie": "en-us",
    "pcModalData": "",
    "pcRepEmail": "",
    "pcRepExt": "",
    "pcRepName": "",
    "pcSelectedCurrFullDesc": "United States Dollar $ (Transactional)",
    "pcSelectedCurrType": "USD",
    "pcSetLanguageLogo": true,
    "pcShopperId": ""
}
```

For it to work, I first need to specify a `prog_id` of "myprogid" and a callback function.
In the callback, I need an alert message containing `pcCountryCode`.

How do I do this?

Comment: JSONP is simply JSON wrapped in a function, which is not what you have.

Comment: Your question is too broad, and *how can I parse multiple parameters in the URL, for example prog_id and callback* suggests you need to start by learning the very basics of server side programming.

Comment: @adeneo It's what I _will_ have once I specify the callback function.

Comment: Can you post the JS code you've already tried so we can see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint should return:

```
myprogid({
    "pcCartCt": 0,
    "pcCountryCode": "au",
    "pcCountrySite": "WWW",
    "pcExpDomCt": 0,
    "pcFirstName": "",
    "pcIsCdc": false,
    "pcIsDiscount": false,
    "pcIsGdEmployee": false,
    "pcIsTrusted": false,
    "pcLanguageCookie": "en-us",
    "pcModalData": "",
    "pcRepEmail": "",
    "pcRepExt": "",
    "pcRepName": "",
    "pcSelectedCurrFullDesc": "United States Dollar $ (Transactional)",
    "pcSelectedCurrType": "USD",
    "pcSetLanguageLogo": true,
    "pcShopperId": ""
});
```

I don't understand your question about parsing multiple parameters. JSONP just expects one special parameter: `callback=myprogid`. This parameter should be used as the name of the function at the beginning of the response.

Comment: The API is expecting an extra parameter of `prog_id` in addition to the callback function. Can someone show me the basic syntax and I will present a problem if it occurs?

Comment: What is the `prog_id` parameter for? How does it differ from the callback function? Anyway, you can have as many parameters as you want, using normal URL syntax: `http://path/to/script?param=value&param=value&param=value...`

Comment: Thanks @barmar! I suspected that'd be the way to use many parameters, but doesn't this method require some special type of URI encoding?

Comment: No special encoding. A URI is a URI.

Comment: If any of the parameters contain special characters, they'll need to be percent-encoded, just like any other URI. Use `encodeURIComponent`, or let jQuery take care of it automatically for you by giving it an object as the `data:` option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after the JS to pull the JSON from the server, this might help. It uses jQuery's promise interface to return a AJAX promise from getData and [when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) the downloading is complete the callback logs the information to the console (or alert).

```
function getData() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: // url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
    data: { prog_id: 'myprogid' }
  });
}

$.when(getData()).then(function (data) {
  console.log(data.pcCountryCode);
});
```

Comment: How do I encode the URL? It sees it as comment? @Andy

Comment: The URL is just the URL like: `http://stackoverflow.com`. The `data` object gets converted to URL parameters automatically. So the complete URL will be `http://stackoverflow.com?prog_id=myprogid`. jQuery handles the callback name automatically, or you can add a new key called `jsonCallback` with the name of the callback wrapper that your server delivers your JSON in. @NoahMCM